# IE11 Developer Tools' "Find" field greyed out

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I'm in IE11 Developer Tools and I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  Once I hit the last search result, the "Find" window grays out and I am unable to ever use search again.

> [image: screenshot]

Tried hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> again, but nothing allows me to regain control of the "Find" box until I restart the browser. Ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem just above every time I use F12 on my application. It's very annoying.

My lame work-around is to first find the code in my local source (i use eclipse) then, back in F12, I use the suitcase icon to find my file. Then I use 'ctrl-g' to go to the line.

F12 has been this way for me for since the beginning of IE11 ... I'm rather surprised such a basic feature can be broken for so long.

Comment: ANNOYINGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG. MS should simply delete IE's code and incorporate a real browser to their OS. It seems that refreshing doesn't fix the feature, you have to close and execute IE again.

Comment: unfortunately if you can't control how/where your JS shows up - this won't work (such as Microsoft Dynamics CRM)...

Comment: I have another workaround: if you want to be able to debug your JavaScript code without needing to search and fiind the proper .js file in the browser, then put `debugger;` in your JavaScript code, before the place you want to start debugging. Then the developer tools will automatically open the file with that line and you can then debug freely.

Comment: I've also used this but it's not so good for the long term. Eventually you forget to remove them and they end up in your production code. I know they only trigger when the debugger is open, but eventually you will get somebody who analyzes your code is not happy about it. Another work-around I used back in IE6 was to intentionally create a runtime error (eg. dog = cat) but eventually of those accidentally get check in, bad news. My latest work-around is called "CHROME", works great :)

Comment: Good news that Edge browser fixes this problem (finally!).  While Edge's F12 looks similar to that of IE11, my guess is that it's a rewrite. It's now able to hold onto breakpoints after refresh and you don't see duplicates of includes from different iframes. So far it's working just as well as the Chrome debugger for me.

Comment: Workaround: Ctrl + A -> Ctrl + C -> Open Notepad -> Ctrl + V :-)

Comment: I've noticed this only happens when you search for a term which doesn't exist and press Enter key. When it happens I just restart IE.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately search operations isn't something that can be cancelled. When this happens you're stuck :(. We're going to be working on correcting this for a future update to F12.

Out of curiosity do you have a page you can share that we can reproduce the issue on? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Andy.  It was on a development build of something I'm working on.  If I can repro it again on a public facing site, I'll let you know.

Comment: Lol I'm actually stunned. IE continues to surprise!! How can such a broken feature remain this long?

Comment: What i find interesting is that, when in this state, if you highlight some text in the debugger and press Ctrl+F, it will search for and find that text, even updating the text in the search box, which remains disabled. IE 11.0.9600.18205

Comment: Those damn failures at IE developement department should be fired wholesome. Stunning how any browser works good now, except IE

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles in here. I have found this to be helpful. There's two steps being described but for me Step 1 alone was the solution

Step 1:

Press Windows key + R and then type “iexplore -extoff” without quotes and press ENTER.

Greetings Chris

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/developer-tools-f12-not-working-grayed-out-in/f8cce77d-efee-488e-a9a8-729ef9189321

Answer (score 0):

Since IE is stucked in the search while running a web application you can use following

**Possible Workaround**:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Open Notepad
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

:-)

Comment: This doesn't help.  The power of this fine feature is to "Find across files", then add breakpoints so you can debug. Not possible in notepad.

Comment: Yeah you are right but this is about getting the possibility to search at this point. I do think IE is stuck because it has to discover multiple files and crashes in that case.